# Upload MP3 file to aws s3 bucket with presigned url and axios: Filesize 0b

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an mp3 file from my reactjs frontend to an aws s3 bucket. I am using presigned urls generated in my expresses backend. everything is working fine and the file name shows up in the was bucket but the file size is always empty (0B). 
An example file looks like this:

```
File {name: "1583327684640.mp3", lastModified: 1583327684640, lastModifiedDate: Wed Mar 04 2020 14:14:44 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 50688, …}
```

Do i have to do something with the file before uploading it?

```
axios.put("presigned-put-url", this.state.audio_file, {headers: {'ContentType': 'audio/mp3'}})
                    .then(res => {
                        setTimeout(()=>{
                            console.log(res);
                        }, 2000)
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log('Sorry, something went wrong');
                        console.log('err', err);
                    });
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Found a solution for my problem. nested "this" was the problem. I saved the file in a constant value and passed the value to axios. now everything is working!